# When creating a form in React .map() does not populate select > options correctly, but works for a normal div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using React (and Redux) and have a form that I need to populate a dropdown with data via an API call.

When I use `.map()` within a standard div the list of results outputs correct. This is the code:

```
<div>
  {categories &&
    categories.map((category, i) => (
      <option
        key={i}
        label={category.categoryName}
        value={category._id}
        name={category.categoryName}
        category={category}
      >
        {category.categoryName}
      </option>
    ))}
</div>
```

When I then try and map the same data within a select/option dropdown it only renders the first result. i.e. **there is no dropdown**. Here's this code:

```
<select
          value={categoryName}
          onChange={(e) => setCategoryName(e.target.value)}
        >
          {categories &&
            categories.map((category, i) => (
              <option
                key={i}
                label={category.categoryName}
                value={category._id}
                name={category.categoryName}
                category={category}
              >
                {category.categoryName}
              </option>
            ))}
```

Here's the [full code for the component in a github gist](https://gist.github.com/pvptowers/cf46821911467a26f5945b1c97d7fd9e)

Thanks in advance for any additional insight you can provide.

Edited to add in actions and reducer:

```
 export const getCategories = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const res = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/category/getallcategories",
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: GET_CATEGORIES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    console.log("2222" + res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: CATEGORY_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

And Reducer:

```
    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_CATEGORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
```

Comment: You need to write onChange in the select. But still it should have rendered. Check this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-sun-rqms0?file=/src/App.js:0-809). Can you reproduce your problem here?

Comment: @AjeetShah thanks for putting together the code playground. I replicated locally on my machine. When I hard code the categories I get the dropdown to work correctly.

When I try and call the categories via the API only the first value populates in the dropdown.

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks again. I have added in the code for the action and reducer with Redux. Does this shine more light on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Hi @AjeetShah it prints: 2222[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: The controller its calling is:

exports.getAllCategories = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const categories = await Category.find({
    user: req.user.id,
  }).populate("tasks");
  res.json(categories);
});

Comment: Thanks @AjeetShah here's the github https://github.com/pvptowers/indie-task-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214872/discussion-between-ajeet-shah-and-paul-towers).

Answer (score 1):

`<select>` tag should contain the value. In your case it is the state: `taskTitle`. Onchange should also be under select. 
In your code you use this useState:

```
const [taskTitle, setTaskTitle] = useState("");
```

So try to change the select to this:

```
<select 
   value={taskTitle}
   onChange={(e) => setTaskTitle(e.target.value)}>
      {categories &&
      categories.map((category, i) => (
         <option
            key={i}
            label={category.categoryName}
            value={category._id}
            name={category.categoryName}
            category={category}
         >
           {category.categoryName}
         </option>
       ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Ajeet & Roman

Thanks for your help.

I tried the above but no luck unfortunately. I did however notice another issue in my original code cause I was calling setTaskTitle, rather than setCategoryName. It was correct in some of my earlier code, but not in the example I provided.

I updated my question and gist, with the latest code.

I still can't get the drop down to populate with all of the results. Could it be an issue with  how the data is structured coming back from the API request?

Thanks again
Paul